# What does …て…て mean?

Tags: grammar, verbs, conjugations, て-form, compound-verbs

I have the following sentence.

> その白い比いない裸体は、薄暮の背景の前に置かれて輝やいていた 。

I understand the use of ~て in ~ている, but I'm confused by two consecutive verbs using ~て as in 置かれ**て**輝やい**て**いた. Should I understand them just as two separate yet consecutive actions? Or does one complete or modify the meaning of the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> その白い比いない裸体は、薄暮の背景の前に置かれ**て**輝やいていた。

I'm assuming that 輝やいて is a typo for 輝いて. (Maybe it's a variant spelling, I don't know).

This て is simply 'and'. So 置かれ**て**輝やいていた is nothing more mysterious than "was set and was shining".

You ask about whether one action modifies the other. Many times a clause in て-form can adverbially modify the following clause, e.g.

> 塀の上に座って食べた

Could be "he sat on the wall and ate" or if you treat the first clause as adverbial it would be "sitting on the wall, he ate". But I feel it would be a bit of a stretch to claim this was the case with your example sentence.

The bit that puzzles me is 比いない, which I'm assuming means "without equal".
So altogether we have:

> That matchless white body was placed in front of a twilight background and was shining.

Weird sentence. What's the context?

Comment: Yeah, I think 比{たぐ}いない is ② in [大辞林's entry for 比い](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%AF%94%E3%81%84): `同じ程度のもの。匹敵するもの。 「 －まれな逸品」 → 類いする ・類いない`

Comment: Yes,  輝やいて is a typo for 輝いて, very common in Mishima's writing, and so 比いない　(たぐいない) can be translated as "incomparable" or "matcheless".  I had some trouble finding it, and apparently it's kind of obscure. It seems that Mishima used 比 as an alternate kanji for 類.